# Proving congruent statement for a prime number $p>10$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, congruences

I have the next statement that has to be proved:

**Let $p$ be a prime number where $p>10$. Prove that $p-2$ has an inverse module $p$, this is, a number $q$ exists where $(p-2)q \equiv 1\mod(p)$.**

I have this so far:

From $(p-2)q \equiv 1\mod(p)$ I know that $(p-2)q=kp+1$ and $p|((p-2)q-1)$.

So, $p|((p-2)q-1)$ is $p|pq-2q-1$.

I don't know which the next step should be exactly. Perhaps something like: $q=24k+r$ where $0 \le r<24$ and trying the different values $r$ can take?

Comment: You really only need to check that $p$ and $p-2$ are relatively prime (by Bezout's Lemma)

Comment: What have you learned recently? Maybe extended Euclid? Think you can use that?

Comment: Why $p>10$ ? It is true for all odd primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=2k+1$. Then

$$2k+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
$$2k \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
$$-2k \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
$$pk-2k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
$$(p-2) k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

Note that we actually proved that the reciprocal is $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that there exist an inverse of $(p-2)$ modulo $p$, which is always true because since $p > 10$, $\gcd(p-2, p) = 1$.